# Move position of an item in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have 6 items in a container:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="one" style="left:100px">...</div>
  <div class="two" style="left:200px">...</div>
  <div class="three" style="left:300px">...</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to change the dom to read:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="one" style="left:100px">...</div>
  <div class="three" style="left:300px">...</div>
  <div class="two" style="left:200px">...</div>
</div>
```

I am trying something different with a masonry layout and need to move things based on size and then re-layout the container. I can't just change the inline style to move them because that would create a gap and when then doing a re-layout the masonry code sees the DOM as it was and then moves them back.

So ideally something like:

```
$(".container > .item").each(function(){
  // if this class="three" then move its
  // outerHTML and insert it after class="one"
}
```

Not sure if this is possible.

The basic problem is that I'm building a masonry layout but more like a windows metro look, horizontal as much as vertical, so want gaps filling with elements which maybe further down the list in the DOM

Comment: *...different with a masonry layout...* different in what sense? Why not use masonry plugin? Also when should the change happen? and at what circumstances?

Comment: Different in the sense that its horizontal, therefore left to right - e.g. 350px high, 4 elements - two of them 350h and in between them and after them 1 element each with height 175 - i want the last 175h to go after the first 175h element

Comment: After and under the first 175h that should have said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `insertAfter()` to achieve this. Also, if you're specifically targeting `.three` the loop is redundant. Try this:

```js
$(".container > .three").insertAfter('.one');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="one" style="left:100px">ONE</div>
  <div class="two" style="left:200px">TWO</div>
  <div class="three" style="left:300px">THREE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! As I'm cycling through the container can I not use $(this).insertAfter(.className'); If i look in inspector it hasn't moved

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `cycling through the container`?

Comment: As in question: $(".container > .item").each(function(){

Comment: Are you using that `each` for another reason than to find the `.three` element then? If not, it's not needed, as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. You can use [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) method for example:

```
$( '.container > .three' ).insertAfter( '.container > .one' );
```

No need to use `each` method.